# Textview show nothing with jni

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to show log file by Textview and Textview log file content is called by jni.
But Textview nothing show(blank black screen),When give just "hello /n How low",was shown by Textview correct.
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello /n How low"); was shown.
**return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str); was not shown.**

--application.java--

```
package com.showlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class showlog extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText( stringFromJNI() );
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    public native String  stringFromJNI();

    public native String  unimplementedStringFromJNI();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("showlog");
    }
}
```

--showlog.c--

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

#define MAX 119 // MAX of one line length of log file
#define Log_file "./Log_file.log" // log file path

jstring
Java_com_showlog_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    char line[120]; // one line length of Log_file
    char str[2000]; // Log_file length
    FILE *fin;

    fin=fopen(Log_file, "r");
    while( ! feof(fin)){
        fgets(line, MAX, fin);
        strcat(str, line);
    }
    fclose(fin);

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);
}
```

Then I try just c code(not be jni lib),It works.
--just show log file--

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 119 // MAX of one line length of log file
#define Log_file "./Log_file.log" // log file path

main()
{
    char line[120]; // one line length of Log_file
    char str[2000]; // Log_file length
    FILE *fin;

    fin=fopen(Log_file, "r");
    while( ! feof(fin)){
        fgets(line, MAX, fin);
        strcat(str, line);
    }
    fclose(fin);

        printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

How does Textview show it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Return value is not proper....just check it.....and return proper value.....